# Fetching column values based on SYSDATE

Tags: oracle, date, oracle10g, dml

I have a table wchih has 2 columns. The definition is

```
CREATE TABLE LOGGING_T
(
  TSTAMP  DATE,
  LINE    VARCHAR2(300)
)
TABLESPACE OPERATIONS
MONITORING
/
```

The colulmn TSTAMP has values like `30-NOV-11`, `29-NOV-11` ... and so on. Now i am doing this query

```
select * from LOGGING_T where TSTAMP >= (SYSDATE - 1)
```

The current system date is `01-DEC-11`. Ideally, the above statement should return records which has TSTAMP = `30-NOV-11` since i am doing `SYSDATE-1` which would be `30-NOV-11`. But it isn't fetching those records. Why?

However, if i do this query

```
select * from LOGGING_T where TSTAMP >= (SYSDATE - 2)
```

Then it fetches records who `TSTAMP` is `30-NOV-11`. Am i doing something wrong in this simple date operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DATE` contains time of day as well as the date.

If `SYSDATE` was `2011-12-01 1:18:00 PM` then `SYSDATE-1` would be `2011-11-30 1:18:00 PM`.

Are the rows you are expecting to find from November 30th before or after the time element?

If you don't care about the time, and only want to filter based on the date, you can use `TRUNC()`:

```
select * 
  from LOGGING_T 
 where TRUNC(TSTAMP) >= TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1);
```

You'll may or may not want to make sure both sides of your comparison operator are `TRUNC()`ed because `TRUNC()` will just force the time element of the date to be midnight.

```
select to_char(trunc(sysdate), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS PM') 
  from dual;

NOW
----------------------
2011-12-01 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: You can omit the TRUNC from `TRUNC(TSTAMP)` because if `TRUNC(TSTAMP) >= TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1)`, it will always be true that `TSTAMP >= TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1)` (and removing this may improve performance if there is an index on TSTAMP).

Answer (score 1):

The value SYSDATE has the time component as well. Most probably the date in your database also has the time component.

Change your query to :

```
select * from LOGGING_T where TSTAMP >= TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1)
```

to see all records which were logged from 00:00 yesterday.

To see the actual timecomponents, use to char.

```
SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
---------
01-DEC-11

  1* select to_char(sysdate,'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') date1 from dual
SQL> /

DATE1
--------------------
01-Dec-2011 16:29:01
```